# Вызвано исключение нарушение доступа для чтения. _Pnext было 0x15E03CC

Tags: c++, исключения

делаю программу-журнал, с данными студентов.
Реализовал операции считки и записи данных в файл
Программа работает корректно, все операции выполняет, но в конце своей работы вылетает исключение
Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.
_Pnext было 0x15E03CC.
Все данные записываются корректно, и считываются тоже, просто конец выполнения программы = аварийный.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Table
{
    

};
class Student
{
public: Student(string sn, string snb, string sad, string mn, string mnb, string mad, string fn, string fnb, string fad)
    {
        this->student_name = sn;
        this->student_number = snb;
        this->student_address = sad;
        this->mother_name = mn;
        this->mother_number = mnb;
        this->mother_address = mad;
        this->father_name = fn;
        this->father_number = fnb;
        this->father_address = fad;
    }
public: Student()
{
    this->student_name = "0";
    this->student_number = "0";
    this->student_address = "0";
    this->mother_name = "0";
    this->mother_number = "0";
    this->mother_address = "0";
    this->father_name = "0";
    this->father_number = "0";
    this->father_address = "0";
}
public:
    string mother_number;
    string father_number;
    string student_number;
    string student_name;
    string mother_name;
    string father_name;
    string student_address;
    string mother_address;
    string father_address;
    void print()
    {
        cout << "Student name is " << student_name << "\nStudent number is " << student_number << "\nStudent address is " << student_address << "Student's mother's name is " << mother_name << "\nStudent's mother's number is " << mother_number << "\nStudent's mother address is " << mother_address << "Student's father's name is " << father_name << "\nStudent's father's number is " << father_number << "\nStudent's father's address is " << father_address << "\n";
    }

};
class event
{
    string name;
    string date;
};


int main()
{
    cout << "Individual project by Maxim Shevchuk IPZ-12_1\n";
    vector<Student> st_list;
    string path = "data.txt";
    Student st;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(path, ifstream::app);
    if (!fin.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Can't open file\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File was open, now we can edit it\n";
        while (fin.read((char*)&st, sizeof(Student)))
        {
            fin.read((char*)&st, sizeof(Student));
            st_list.push_back(st);
        }
        fin.close();
    }
    
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "What do you wand to do:\n1 - is add information about student\n2 - is find full information about student\n-3 - is edit information about student\n4 - is delete information about student\n";
        short choice;
        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            cout << "Lets enter all known information about the student\nTo begin with enter student's name, if you dont know - write: nothing\n";
            string sn;
            cin >> sn;
            cout << "Now enter his number, if you dont know - write: nothing\n";
            string snb;
            cin >> snb;
            cout << "Now enter his address, if you dont know - write: nothing\n";
            string sad;
            cin >> sad;
            cout << "Now lets enter all known information about his parents, lets start from student's mother\nEnter name of student's mother, if you dont know - write: nothing\n";
            string mn;
            cin >> mn;
            cout << "Now enter mother's number, if you dont know - write: nothing\n";
            string mnb;
            cin >> mnb;
            cout << "Now enter mother's address, if you dont know - write: nothing\n";
            string mad;
            cin >> mad;
            cout << "Now lets enter all known information about student's father\nLets start from name, if you dont know - write: nothing\n";
            string fn;
            cin >> fn;
            cout << "Now enter father's number, if you dont know - write: nothing\n";
            string fnb;
            cin >> fnb;
            cout << "Now enter father's address, if you dont know - write: nothing\n";
            string fad;
            cin >> fad;
            Student std(sn, snb, sad, mn, mnb, mad, fn, fnb, fad);
            st_list.push_back(std);
            break;
        }
        break;
    
    }
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(path, ofstream::app);
    if (!fout.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Can't open file\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File was open, now we can edit it\n";
        for (int a = 0; a < st_list.size(); a++)
        {
            fout.write((char*)&st_list[a], sizeof(Student));
        }
    }
    fout.close();
    
}
```

Comment: `fin.read((char*)&st, sizeof(Student))` что за хрень? Что Вы хотели сделать? `Student` не является POD типом, его побитовое копирование и/или инициализация до добра не доведёт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> все операции выполняет, но в конце своей работы вылетает исключение

Основная проблема в том, что `Student` не является POD типом.

При операции `fout.write((char*)&st_list[a], sizeof(Student))` в файл записывается не сама информация, а указатели на неё.

При операции `fin.read((char*)&st, sizeof(Student))` считается не информация, а указатели. Поскольку дело происходит в том же самом приложении, то чтение информации полей класса всё равно проходит.

Однако, когда дело доходит до деструкторов, то некоторые части `string` и др., начинают повторно удаляться, что и вызывает исключение.

P.S.
Но и сделать его POD типом тоже, хотя и будет работать, но нехорошо, некошерно. По-хорошему, `Student` надо преобразовывать в транспортное (сетевое) представление, например, JSON.